# Derivative of an autonomous system of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

> Consider the $N$-dimensional autonomous system of ODEs
>   $$\dot{x}= f(x),$$
>   where a locally unique solution $x(t)$, starting from the initial condition $x$, is denoted as $x(t)=\phi(t,x)$. Show that
>
> $$\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}\phi(t,x)\Big)f(x)=f(\phi(t,x))$$

Here is my proposed solution.

We are given that $\dot{x}= f(x),$ so we know that

$$\frac{dx(t)}{dt}=f(x(t))$$

If we integrate both sides with respect to $t$, we will get

$$\int_{t_0}^{t}\frac{dx(t)}{dt}dt =\int_{t_0}^{t} f(x(s)) ds$$

Therefore,

$$x(t) = x_0 + \int_{t_0}^{t} f(x(s)) ds$$

where the integration constant is chosen such that $x(t_0)=x_0$. As $x(t)=\phi(t,x)$, we have

$$\phi(t,x) = x_0 + \int_{t_0}^{t} f(x(s)) ds$$

Hence,

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial{t}}(t,x) & = 0 + \frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}\int_{t_0}^{t} f(x(s)) ds \\
 & = f(x(t))\\
 & = f(\phi(t,x))
\end{split}
\end{equation}

where the second equality follows from the fundamental theorem of calculus. Next, we are given that

1. $\phi$ depends on $(t,x)$.
2. $x$ depends on $t$.

Therefore, by the chain rule,

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial{t}}(t,x) & = \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial{x}}(t,x)\frac{dx}{dt} \\
 & = \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial{x}}(t,x)f(x)\\
 & = f(\phi(t,x))
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Thus, $\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}\phi(t,x)\Big)f(x)=f(\phi(t,x))$.

It does seem rather strange that I concluded that

$$\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial{t}}(t,x) = \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial{x}}(t,x)\frac{dx}{dt}$$

This must be because $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial{t}}(t,x) = \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial{x}}(t,x)\frac{dx}{dt}$ instead of $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial{t}}(t,x) = \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial{t}}(t,x)\frac{dx}{dt}$ because of the chain rule.

Is this approach correct? Please let me know if there are any better alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make the flow definition more specific, such as not re-using the simple $x$ in two different meanings, you could define the flow as 
$$x(t)=ϕ(t;x_0) ~~ \text{ where } ~~ x(0)=ϕ(0;x_0)=x_0.$$

---

You need to invoke the autonomous nature of the ODE which has as consequence that $t\mapsto ϕ_t$ is a group action/representation of the additive group $(\Bbb R,+)$. This means that $ϕ_t\circ ϕ_s=ϕ_{t+s}$, or 
$$
ϕ(t+s;x_0)=ϕ(t;ϕ(s;x_0))\iff x(t+s)=ϕ(t;x(s)).
$$ 
From your point-of-view the closest variant might be $x(t)= ϕ(t-s;x(s))$. Anyway, to get the $x$-derivative of $ϕ$ involved you need first some kind of explicit variability in the $x$-argument of $ϕ$ which is easiest done by moving the initial point along the solution curve.

Taking, in the first variant, the derivative for $s$ at $s=0$ then gives indeed by the chain rule
$$
f(ϕ(t+s;x_0))=\frac{∂}{∂s}ϕ(t;ϕ(s;x_0))=\frac{∂ϕ}{∂x}(t;ϕ(s;x_0))\cdot f(ϕ(s;x_0))\\
\overset{s=0}\implies 
f(ϕ(t;x_0))=\frac{∂ϕ}{∂x}(t;x_0)f(x_0)\\
$$